# Find peak values of a set of values

Tags: linear-algebra

In a dataset like this which represent a serie of angles:

[image]

How to find the weighted average of each "band" (in that case would be 0.1 and -90 something) whilst ignoring potential random points.

I was thinking of the FFT transform but that might not be the right approach.

Perhaps transforming that in a graph alike Gaussian distribution and find the peaks?

(I test in python)

Comment: Why not just set a cutoff, say, at -50?

Comment: That would only work in specific cases, I'm looking for a "correct" mathematical way of doing it

Comment: Then I think you need to define the different bands properly